# Change current playing track

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I am working on an program in Java that has to be used to create and collect songs from a playlist. I have already got it to print, add and shuffle songs from the playlist, and I have to make it change the currently playing track (current track title, artist name - and album) to the next track in the playlist. When the end of the playlist is reached it has to automatically start over from the beginning. I have to use the `Iterator` methods `next` and `hasNext` in some ways, but I have no idea how. I have already started on it, but I have not hit a wall. I am still very new at Java, so I would really appreciate some help, a hint even.

Here is the code:

```
public void next() { 
    ListIterator itr = songs.listIterator();  
    if (itr.hasNext()) {                  
        itr.next();
    }
}

public String currentTrackTitle() {   
    return null;
}

public String currentArtistName() {
    return null;
}

public String currentAlbumName() {
    return null;
}

public int currentTrackLength() {
    return 0;
}

//}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of those methods? At least 4 of them look useless for me.

Comment: One hint would be if you get to the end of the list, the `hasNext()` will return null. If it does, then you just set the nest song to the first song in the list.

Comment: @ROMANIA The four methods are from an interface MusicPlaylist, so I can not change those right? However I have a hard time, myself, seeing how to include all of them :/

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai yes so that when it reaches the end it should start over. But I have a hard time seeing how to use that hasNext method. So if hasNext (there is a next song in the playlist), then that song should be set to currentSong. But I do not know how to do that :/ I have two instance variables  currentSong and index that I think I should use for storing information? I just think I am misunderstanding how to use the hasNext method?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the result of itr.next() in variable.

Comment: Like this: itr.next = currentSong; ?